# Trying to inject a content.js script in my chrome extention (Added right permmissions)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to inject a content.js script in my chrome extension through my background.js file - I've added the "scripting" and "activeTab permission but it still says:

-"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript')"

```
//manifest.json
{
"name": "WeWatch",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 3,
"permissions": [ 
  "tabs", "scripting","activeTab"
],
"background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js"
  
  
},
"action":{
  "default_icon":{
    "16":"pics/logo.png",
    "48":"pics/logo.png",
    "128":"pics/logo.png"  
  },
  "default_popup": "htmls/dif_popup.html",
  "default_title": "WeWatch$"
}
```

}

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
//background.js
function room_process(){

chrome.scriptng.executeScript(
    {
    target:{tabId: room[3]}, //room[3]=tabId
    files:["content.js"]
    }
    
);
```

}

Comment: you typed "chrome.scriptng.executeScript" it must be this "chrome.scripting.executeScript". Also, you can run the content script from the manifest, see this example https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#static-declarative

Comment: @user1731468 ,  Thank you!!! OMG - and thanks about the tip with the manifest, but i want to inject the script at a spesific time. I am making a chrome extention that can make users wath togethor videos on youtube itself and i want to execute the script when the user enters the watching room and not based on the url